# Discarding local commits making current workspace same as central repo in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a gigantic repo and it takes a while to clone. Every time I make a few commits and realize I have goofed up, I end up deleting the current clone and re-cloning the repo. While this works, it is very very time consuming. Is there any command that I can use to just discard all my local changes and make my working folder look like my last pull?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options and both below assume that the changes only exist locally in your repo:

1. Have an additional local reference clone that only ever represents what the remote repo looks like. Then you can delete your current throwaway repo and reclone locally from your reference copy, which is much, *much* faster.
2. Utilize the [`strip`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/StripExtension) function which will let you trim off branches of history. Please be very careful deleting history since it really is a double edged sword.

Comment: I would not even suggest 1, since 2 is safe enough. From what I gather, the commits are still in draft (on the local repo only), so strip will eliminate completely the commits. And even if you strip a changeset that is already public, it will simply get pulled back again at the next sync. The only case where it can be tricky is when you strip from sub-repos changesets that are already referenced in the main.

Comment: @mithun_daa Nope. `hg strip` actually edits the history and removes changesets, leaving no trace behind.